# restricting access of php page till user logs in

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im trying to write a script that restricts the access of user to a page until he has logged in with username and password. I keep getting undefined index file for username and password? any one have any suggestions??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> Exercise 3</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $name = “Frank”;
    $age = “28”;
    var_dump($name);
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($name);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($age);
    echo "<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're looking at two `$_POST` variables, that haven't necessarily been set - they'll be undefined when the page first loads, for example. You should add a check to see if the user is actually trying to log in, and only run the code if they are.

Comment: If you are getting "Undefined index 'file'" as the error somewhere you are trying to reference 'file' in an array. `$array['file']` I don't see it in this code so my guess is it is in `config.php`.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: config.php only contains host, user, password and db. ive a log in file that gets the username and password. I want to restrict access to report.php which contains a displayed version of mysql database

Comment: i use require_once("logincheck.php"); in the file i want restricted

Comment: holy sql injection, batman

Comment: its on a portable server, its not guna be released or anything. its nly for a project in class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather a big topic. The easiest way to protect a directory is to have the web server do the grunt work and setup an htaccess file. http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/ is a online tool to do that.

To do it through PHP you need to get the user login and then give a session cookie to tell the other URLS if he is logged in. If the cookie is hackable or the other urls assume he is logged in then he can easily bypass your login. Unless it is only a single page you want to secure.

If you want to store users in a database there are a number of security issues that appear quickly. The user input must be completely cleaned of any charactors that may allow for hacks.

Comment: this is only a simple project for class. All i want is to restrict user access to page until they log in. I have log in set up and register. The file above is to check if the user is logged in

Comment: Is part of what they are looking for to make sure secure actually means secure?  what if user name entered in looks something like ths user_login=admin&amp;user_email=foobar@gmail.com&amp;user_pass=$P$BSQhEGPcLUPtNHcu93k3aSddiQQsO6/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running even when no login form is being submitted. You need to check if a login attempt it actually being made:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST') {
    ... process login attempt ...
}

display_login_form();
```

And even then, to practice proper "safe programming" techniques, you shouldn't assume that a particular form variable will always be present:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
   $username = $_POST['username'];
} else {
   die("Username cannot be blank");
}
```